# IndexError: list index out of range for multidimensional list

Tags: python-3.x

I know the matrix is empty, but I would like to use a multidimensional list and insert a value based on the row and column. My script is as follows:

```
def round1(plain_text, key):
    state_matrix = list()
    count = 0
    row = 0
    column = 0
    element_no = 0
    first_time = 'Y'
    for value in plain_text:
        if element_no == 1:
            row += 1
            element_no += 1
        elif element_no == 2:
            row -= 1
            column += 1
            element_no += 1
        elif element_no == 3:
            row += 1
            element_no += 1
        else:
            element_no += 1

        state_matrix[row][column] = value

    print(state_matrix)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range for multidimensional list
```

Can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to be "empty":

- all values are `None` (or some other "not-a-value" placeholder)
- no values exist at all -- not `None`, not `0`, not `null`, nothing

In your code `state_matrix` is the second type -- there is absolutely nothing in it.  This means that *any* index you try to use is invalid.

You need to either grow the list as you go with, for example, `state_matrix.append(...)`, or create an empty (with a "no-value" placeholder) state_matrix at the beginning with, for example, `state_matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` ... but then you have to know how big it will become.

Comment: state_matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
using this way im restricting the size of list. There's no other way around?